# Configuring osm2po.config to parse both car and foot routes

Tags: osm2po

I have tried to play around with the `osm2po.config` file, to parse both car and foot routes but have had little success.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, decide which roads are candidates for walking:

Add "foot" to the list of allowed types

```
wtr.tag.highway.residential=1,32,50,car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.pedestrian=1,62,5,bike|foot
```

Set the finalMask in order to take them into account

```
wtr.finalMask=car|bike|foot
```

If you are only interested in walkable roads, set

```
wtr.finalMask=foot
```

Set

```
wtr.maxSpeedOverrides=false
```

if you don't want your default-speeds being overridden by osm's maxSpeed-Tag.

That's it